# When should I use gdal_merge.py?

Tags: gdal, performance, gdal-translate, gdal-merge, gdalbuildvrt

When building a single georeferenced image from a collection of tiles, `gdalbuildvrt` followed by `gdal_translate` [is *much* faster than `gdal_merge.py`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22602542/674064).

In my own measurements of

```
gdal_merge.py \
        --config GDAL_CACHEMAX 3000 \
        --optfile filelist.txt \
        -o $output_file
```

and

```
gdalbuildvrt \
        -input_file_list filelist.txt \
        $tmpdirname/out.vrt
gdal_translate \
        $tmpdirname/out.vrt \
        -of GTiff \
        $output_file
```

on a collection of 46 GeoTIFFs of 600×600px each, I got over 30min vs. 1min 58s.

It seems strange that the detour via a virtual dataset is so much more performant. Does it have any downsides?

When should I use `gdal_merge.py` instead, anyway? (And if there aren't any cases for that with `gdal_merge.py`'s current implementation, why isn't `gdal_merge.py` instead just implemented as an alias to these two actions?)

Comment: According to [this mailing list post](https://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/gdal-dev/2018-March/048335.html), `gdal_translate` doesn't properly handle alpha / mask / nodata, while `gdal_merge.py` handles them as binary mask and `gdalmerge` does proper alpha blending when applicable.

Comment: So when having overlapping inputs, `gdal_translate` might not give the desired result.